# Python nested lists, all combinations

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools, nested-lists

I have nested lists of the form:

```
['A', 'B', ['a0', 'a1', 'a2'], 'C', 'D', ['a0', 'a1', 'a2'], 'E', 'F', ['a0', 'a1', 'a2']]
```

and I would like to generate all the combinations with respect to the sublist `['a0', 'a1', 'a2']` of the form:

```
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a0'], 'E', 'F', ['a0']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a0'], 'E', 'F', ['a1']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a0'], 'E', 'F', ['a2']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a1'], 'E', 'F', ['a0']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a1'], 'E', 'F', ['a1']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a1'], 'E', 'F', ['a2']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a2'], 'E', 'F', ['a0']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a2'], 'E', 'F', ['a1']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a2'], 'E', 'F', ['a2']]
.             .                 .
.             .                 .
.             .                 .
['A', 'B', ['a2'], 'C', 'D', ['a2'], 'E', 'F', ['a2']]
```

etc. In total 27 27 lists. I know I have to use `itertools` package but I cannot figure out how. Any idea welcomed.

Comment: Why is it `['a0']` in the outputted array instead of just `'a0'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do, (if there is only one single nested level):

```
from itertools import product

lst = ['A', 'B', ['a0', 'a1', 'a2'], 'C', 'D', ['a0', 'a1', 'a2'], 'E', 'F', ['a0', 'a1', 'a2']]


def nested_product(ls):
    lst_positions = [l for l in ls if isinstance(l, list)]
    for p in product(*lst_positions):
        it = iter(p)
        yield [e if not isinstance(e, list) else [next(it)] for e in lst]


for pr in nested_product(lst):
    print(pr)
```

**Output** *(partial)*

```
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a0'], 'E', 'F', ['a0']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a0'], 'E', 'F', ['a1']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a0'], 'E', 'F', ['a2']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a1'], 'E', 'F', ['a0']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a1'], 'E', 'F', ['a1']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a1'], 'E', 'F', ['a2']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a2'], 'E', 'F', ['a0']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a2'], 'E', 'F', ['a1']]
['A', 'B', ['a0'], 'C', 'D', ['a2'], 'E', 'F', ['a2']]
['A', 'B', ['a1'], 'C', 'D', ['a0'], 'E', 'F', ['a0']]
...
```

An alternative solution, using [yield from](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) (Python 3.3+), is the following:

```
def build_nested_list(ls, it):
    return [e if not isinstance(e, list) else [next(it)] for e in ls]


def nested_product(ls):
    lst_positions = (li for li in ls if isinstance(li, list))
    yield from (build_nested_list(ls, iter(p)) for p in product(*lst_positions))
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one layer of nesting:

```py
import itertools

def combos(lst):
    # prep a copy without sublists so a little less can be copied
    copy = []
    lindices = []
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(v, list):
            # if it's a list we note the index
            lindices.append(i)
            # we append None to the copy since it'll get overwritten anyway
            copy.append(None)
        else:
            copy.append(v)
    ret = []
    # we cartesian product all the list arguments
    # the * is argument destructuring
    for items in itertools.product(*[lst[i] for i in lindices]):
        # we make a copy of the list
        curcopy = copy.copy()
        for i, item in zip(lindices, items):
            # we assign the elements
            curcopy[i] = item
        # we append the copy to the return
        ret.append(curcopy)
    return ret

test = ['A', 'B', ['a0', 'a1', 'a2'], 'C', 'D', ['b0', 'b1', 'b2'], 'E', 'F', ['c0', 'c1', 'c2']]
print(combos(test))
```

If you do actually want `'a0'` in the return value to be wrapped in an array, then you can replace `ret.append(curcopy)` with `ret.append([curcopy])`.